# Permissions in flutter background_fetch headless task

Tags: android, flutter, permissions, android-permissions, background-fetch

I've got an Android app written in Dart using the Flutter framework.  When it's first opened up, it requests permission to access location in the background.  When the user opens the app using the launcher icon, this all works fine.

I use the `background_fetch` package to configure a headless task that runs on boot.  This works, but it appears the context this runs in doesn't have the same permissions as the app.  I check the permissions like this:

```
      status = await Permission.location.status;
      locationGranted = status.isGranted;
      status = await Permission.locationAlways.status;
      locationAlwaysGranted = status.isGranted;

      if (locationAlwaysGranted) {
        ...
      }
```

If I run this code from the app's `main()` then the body of the `if` statement is executed; when it runs from the headless task after the phone restarts, the body of the `if` block is not executed.

Is there a way to get the headless task to have the same permissions as the app?  Or is there a better way to restart background location tracking after a phone restart?

The background-fetch task is configured like this:

```
  BackgroundFetch.registerHeadlessTask(headlessTask);
  BackgroundFetch.configure(BackgroundFetchConfig(
    minimumFetchInterval: 15,
    stopOnTerminate: false,
    enableHeadless: true,
    startOnBoot: true,
    requiresBatteryNotLow: false,
    requiresStorageNotLow: false,
    requiresCharging: false,
    requiresDeviceIdle: false,
    requiredNetworkType: NetworkType.NONE
  ), (String taskId) {
    ...
    BackgroundFetch.finish(taskId);
  });
  BackgroundFetch.scheduleTask(TaskConfig(
    delay: 0,
    periodic: false,
    startOnBoot: true,
    taskId: "gfz_on_boot",
    enableHeadless: true
  ));
```

**Edited to add** this is the stack trace that appears in the flutter logs:

```
E/flutter ( 6464): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(PermissionHandler.PermissionManager, Unable to detect current Android Activity., null, null)
E/flutter ( 6464): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:607:7)
E/flutter ( 6464): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:167:18)
E/flutter ( 6464): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6464): #2      MethodChannelPermissionHandler.requestPermissions (package:permission_handler_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_permission_handler.dart:71:9)
E/flutter ( 6464): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6464): #3      GFZModel.updatePermissions (package:gfz_app/model.dart:349:24)
E/flutter ( 6464): <asynchronous suspension>
```

This makes sense at one level - there is no current activity in the background task - but how can we use permissions in background tasks?